# Chicago Boss boss_db:find on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, chicagoboss

I am trying to understand the boss_db module to access the mongodb I have setup in Chicago boss

I found an example to access that data using boss_db from [Here](https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/boss_db)

example:

```
Puppy = boss_db:find("puppy-1"),
io:format("Puppy's name: ~p~n", [Puppy:name()]).
```

but when I try this all with my code

```
Cl= boss_db:find(clientList, [], [{limit,1}]),
io:format("Puppy's name: ~p~n", [Cl:datablock()]),
```

I get this error message

```
[{erlang,apply,
     [[{clientList,"clientList-53e30e8b10af5d1503000287",
           <<"Sheet1">>,<<"Jason@email.com.au\n">>,
           <<131,108,0,0,0,3,104,2,107,0,6,70,105,101,108,100,49,
             107,...>>}],
      datablock,[]],
     []},
 {pigeon_greeting_controller,template,3,
     [{file,
          "/home/jason/pigeon/src/controller/pigeon_greeting_controller.erl"},
      {line,57}]},
 {boss_web_controller,call_controller_action,3,
     [{file,"src/boss/boss_web_controller.erl"},{line,363}]},
 {boss_web_controller,apply_action,4,
     [{file,"src/boss/boss_web_controller.erl"},{line,355}]},
 {boss_web_controller,execute_action_inner,9,
     [{file,"src/boss/boss_web_controller.erl"},{line,334}]},
 {boss_web_controller_handle_request,process_dynamic_request,
     4,
     [{file,"src/boss/boss_web_controller_handle_request.erl"},
      {line,242}]},
 {boss_web_controller_handle_request,process_request,4,
     [{file,"src/boss/boss_web_controller_handle_request.erl"},
      {line,228}]},
 {boss_web_controller_handle_request,set_timer,7,
     [{file,"src/boss/boss_web_controller_handle_request.erl"},
      {line,148}]}]
```

I know I am getting returned data cos I can do

```
[{clientList, _,_,_, Datablock}] = boss_db:find(clientList, [], [{limit,1}]),
io:format("data block is : ~p~n", [Datablock]).
```

and it comes back without a problem

My preference would be to find it by a field name and not pattern matching as the pattern may change at some point.

am I looking at old examples or is it that this example only works with relational db. I am having trouble finding site that has some simple examples on how to do this

Comment: What does your model look like? I am questioning whether CL:datablock() is backed by a field Datablock on your model. Is it possibly DataBlock in your model which would make the accessor function data_block()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you are referencing uses boss_db:find/1 which returns a record. Your code uses Boss_db:find/3 which returns a list of records.

Your example above, with my database, reproduces the problem

```
1> CL = boss_db:find(customer, [], [{limit,1}]).
... snip ...

2> CL:id().
** exception error: bad argument
 in function  apply/3
    called as apply([{customer,"customer-1","TEST1","First Test Customer",
                               "red",
                               {{2014,8,12},{15,7,21}},
                               ["2014",45,
                                ["0",56],
                                45,"12",32,"15",58,
                                ["0",55],
                                58,"21",46,"486989"]}],
                    id,[])
```

but recognizing that boss_db returns a list, and all works:

```
1> [CL]= boss_db:find(customer, [], [{limit,1}]).
... snip ...
2> CL:id().
"customer-1"
```

Hope this helps